# Why does Ubuntu think that my iMac is a laptop?

Tags: laptop, mac, acpi

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my late-2010 iMac. I am dual-booting OS X 10.8.3 and Ubuntu. For some reason, Ubuntu thinks that my system is a laptop. Under the "Displays" settings, it only says laptop. I ran the 'sudo laptop-detect -v' command in a terminal, and it says "We're a laptop (ACPI batteries found)" does anyone know why this is? It doesn't affect my system or anything, it's just kind of annoying and I would like to change it. Is this possible, or is this just a bug in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how ubuntu determines this, but it probably thinks that due to the hardware commonly used in imacs. I don't know exactly what hardware the 2010 imac has, but if it's anything like the 2012 imac then it has laptop grade components, ie a laptop grade gpu and cpu.